# A Game of Tug of War

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, stress-strain

So this question came in physics exam during 8th grade.
The question was:

**Two teams ,Team A and Team B are playing a game of tug of war. If the rope breaks near the side of team A ,then which team pulled the rope with greater force?**

I could not find any convincing answer for this.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: It is definitely not a homework question. I just wanted to know whether some assumptions are required or some basic concepts that I am not aware of.

Comment: The term "homework-like question" does not only apply to actual homework assignments here. Please show what you have tried and if there is some specific *concept* (instead of answer) that you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

So while the rope tension is normally the same between the teams, the only difference in tension will be when a team pulls harder it will accelerate the rope towards them. Since the rope has mass the tension will be slightly higher right next to the team pulling harder and accelerating it. When team A pulls harder the tension next to B is only enough to accelerate team B. The tension next to A has to accelerate the rope between A and B and team B.

Comment: The tension in the rope is the same for both teams.  Whoever pushes harder against the ground wins the tug.

Comment: @David White when a rope with mass is under acceleration from a greater net force at one end then the tension in the rope is not the same.

Comment: When the rope is horizontal, gravity cannot add tension to the rope with decreasing height.  This means that the tension in the rope is the same throughout the rope when people are executing tug of war.  And note - there cannot be a greater net force at one end of the rope based on Newton's 3rd law.  There can only be one net force on the whole rope, and that net force accelerates the whole rope and all the people in the same direction.

Comment: When A pulls harder than B the whole system accelerates towards A. This has nothing to do with gravity other than gravity and acceleration are equivalent.